# Using node-cron with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, cron

I'm trying to write a coffeescript script for hubot that makes use of node-cron. I found an example like so and it works great:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  cronJob = require('cron').CronJob
  new cronJob('0 */1 * * * *', everyMinute(robot), null, true)

everyMinute = (robot) ->
  -> robot.messageRoom '#billing', 'hey brah!'
```

However, this is my current script. It doesn't ever seem to fire the node event. I'm basically trying to check the status of a remote API every minute and set the result in hubot's brain. What am I doing wrong here? This is basically the first coffeescript I've ever written so still find my feet.

```
module.exports = (robot) ->

  cronJob = require('cron').CronJob
  new cronJob('0 */1 * * * *', getOnPoint, null, true)

  getOnPoint = ->
    robot.http("https://#{pagerDutyDomain}.pagerduty.com/api/v1/schedules/#{pagerDutyService}")
    .headers(Authorization: "Token token=\"#{pagerDutyToken}\"", Accept: 'application/json')
      .query(since: '2015-11-23T21:15:49Z', until: '2015-11-23T22:15:49Z')
      .get() (err,res,body) ->
        if res.statusCode isnt 200
          msg.send "Request didn't come back HTTP 200 :( got back #{body}"
          return

        json = JSON.parse(body)
        onpoint_person = json.schedule.final_schedule.rendered_schedule_entries[0].user.email
        robot.logger.debug "Setting onpoint to #{onpoint_person}"
        robot.brain.set 'onpoint_person', onpoint_person.split("@")[0]
```

I looked at the JS that the coffeescript compiled to and it's clear that the way I'm declaring the function is important, but I have no idea why.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `getOnPoint` is never called?

Comment: Is it not being called inside the cronjob?
   new cronJob('0 */1 * * * *', getOnPoint, null, true)

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't ever seem to fire the node event"? Which event?

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to do "anything". I've tried changing the code to:

`cronJob = require('cron').CronJob
new cronJob('0 */1 * * * *', robot.emit "testing", null, true)`

The function it's meant to call every 1 minute never gets executed..

Comment: The first call happens after 1 minute. Try testing with `* * * * * *`. It should call every second.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, if you notice he has two ->'s in his method, I worked around it by making another method between the cronJob and the one you want to use.

```
new cronJob('0 */1 * * * *', getOnPointMethod(), null, true)

getOnPointMethod = ->
  -> getOnPoint()
```

This will work don't know how elegant or good a solution it is but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the function getOnPoint above the initialization cron